# Reload part of a page AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an AJAX function that reloads the current page. Now I don't want to reload the whole page, is it possible to get for example the innerHTML of div#footer in http.responseText? 
What I actually want to do is:

```
document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = http.responseText.getElementById("footer");
```

But of course it's not possible like that, and I don't want to rewrite the whole page that for example it only prints out the footer if a GET variable exists..
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest it and parse it as a string?

```
h=http.responseText;
s1=h.substring(h.indexOf('<div id="footer"'));
s1=s1.substring(s1.indexOf('>')+1);
s1=s1.substring(0,s1.indexOf('</div>'));
document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML=s1
```

there

but if you have any more divs in footer this will grab it until the next div's end - create a new div after footer's `</div> e.g.: </div><div id="end"></div>`

and instead of

```
s1=s1.substring(0,s1.indexOf('</div>'));
```

do:

```
s1=s1.substring(0,s1.indexOf('</div><div id="end">'));
```

Comment: I already thought about that, but I didn't find a working regex expression for that..

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`document.createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment).